# Building a List from another list and other sources in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have a `ClassA` with 10 fields and have the following list populated with 100 records.

```
List<ClassA> abc = new List<ClassA>();
```

I have another class `ClassB` with 12 fields where 10 fields are same as Class and 2 extra fields which are lets say harcoded ,viz `field11` and `field12`. Property names of ClassA and ClassB are same.

I have tried looping `ClassA` list and build `ClassB` object inside the loop and keep adding to the list of `ClassB` with 2 extra columns.
But is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: So, essentially `abc.Select(a => new ClassB(a)).ToList()` ?

Comment: I need to populate two other columns also in ClassB list along with 10 fields of ClassA

Comment: @VA1267 You mentioned that the two extra fields are hardcoded. So you can populate those fields in the `ClassB` constructor, right?

Comment: also, instead of `abc.Select(a => new ClassB(a)).ToList()` you can use `abc.ConvertAll(a => new ClassB(a)).` which is much more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use select :

```
var def = abc.Select(a => new ClassB{
field1 = a.field1,
field2 = a.field2,
.... 
field11 = default,
field12 = default,
}).ToList()
```

Comment: as @dmitriy-grebennikov said, Automapper is a good approach also

Comment: Automapper is massive overkill for a simple task like this

Comment: That's a textbook case for AutoMapper, a lot of fields to assign manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use auto mapping libraries. Like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) or [Mapster](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster)
They can map your entities by properties naming convention. And also you can setup specific rules for each mapping.
Please look for documentation in above links.